# System error 58 while accessing shares on Windows 7 from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7

I am getting a weird one. I am getting error following error message while accessing Windows 7 shares from Windows XP.

> System error 58 has occurred. the
>   specified server cannot perform the
>   requested operation

Both machines are in same domain. Windows XP machines can view and access all other shares except for the ones that are on Windows 7. Both machines do not have a software firewall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok guys here is the answer.

the problem was NTML response was not setup on both sides. I had to setup following on both xp and wind7 and a restart did the trick.

1. GPedit.msc
2. Windows Settings. Expand “Local Policies” and select “Security Options”
3. Alternate : Type secpol.msc to get editor up then
4. Locate “Network Security: LAN Manager Authentication Level” in the list and double-click it.
5. Change the setting from “Send NTMLv2 response only” to “Send LM & NTLM – use NTLMv2 session if negotiated”

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for changes needed to Win7 to allow XP (pre Vista) clients to connect to shares and printers on the Win7 machine:

1. Start - Run (Windows - R) - GPedit.msc
2. In the Group Policy Editor window that opens, in the left pane, expand:

   - Local Computer Policy

     - Computer Configuration

       - Windows Settings

         - Security Settings
3. click on "IP Security Policies on Local Computer" under that
4. In right pane, double click on SecNet RAS/VPN Client POlicy (the only entry)
5. In the new properties dialog that opens, in the Rules tab, scroll to the bottom of the list
6. check "" Default response (earlier viersions of Windows Only)
7. click OK